# What's more natural - "when" or "what" time would be convenient to meet today?

Tags: formal-language

Does it sound natural to ask in an email:

> Could you please let me know what time and where would be convenient for you to meet today?

I thought it is more appropriate to use "when" if I don't know the date. Since I already knew the day, I wanted to specifically ask the time. Am I correct?

Comment: You can check these things in Word. We really don't edit things here. Thanks.

Comment: The answer is yes, but the question is off-topic here.

Comment: Welcome! Although proofreading requests are off-topic, you can use the "edit" button to make this a valid question by explaining what part of the sentence you're concerned about and why.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Andy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's fine.

I'd probably say "please let me know when and where ..." It sounds a little more consistent to match "when" and "where" then "what time" and "where".

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was pretty sure it was grammatically correct. But I wasn't sure if it has a natural flow.